# MySQL join results of two unrelated queries

Tags: mysql, join

I'm a novice SQL-er trying to join the results of two unrelated queries into a table. I've looked at as many examples in SO using JOIN, UNION, nested SELECT statements etc. but none seem to work. Here are my tables and relevant columns:

Users:
user_ID | username

Events:
event_ID | user_ID | user_ID_affected

The situation is a multiplayer game. What I am trying to do is "lookup" usernames based on user IDs for every event which occurs. I can get the lookup of username from Users based on an event in Events, but not the usernameAffected from Users at the same time.

Here are my queries which both work individually:

```
SELECT Events.event_ID AS eventID, Events.user_ID AS userID, Users.username
AS username1, Events.user_ID_affected AS userIDAffected
FROM Events
LEFT JOIN Users ON Events.user_ID = Users.user_ID
WHERE Events.event_ID > 11337
ORDER BY Events.event_ID ASC;
```

and:

```
SELECT Users.username AS usernameAffected
FROM Users
WHERE Users.user_ID = Events.user_ID_affected;
```

But try as I might I can't combine them. The output I am hoping for is a result with columns like this:

eventID | userID | username1 | userIDaffected | usernameAffected

Any thoughts?

Comment: `both work individually` ... your second query won't even run.

Comment: You're right Tim - and now I can't find the query that worked :( But the logic is the same: lookup usernames from the Users table where the userID matches the userID from that event.

Comment: Can you show us sample data along with your expected output table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think all you need here is to join twice to the `Users` table, once for the user who acts, and a second time for the user receiving the action:

```
SELECT
    e.event_ID AS eventID,
    e.user_ID AS userID,
    u1.username AS username,
    e.user_ID_affected AS userID_affected,
    u2.username AS username_affected
FROM Events e
LEFT JOIN Users u1
    ON e.user_ID = u1.user_ID
LEFT JOIN Users u2
    ON e.user_ID_affected = u2.user_ID
WHERE
    e.event_ID > 11337
ORDER BY
    e.event_ID ASC;
```